# how to generate getting the first column of excel and get the match data in database which is mssql. C# language

Tags: c#

I want to get the first column of excel and auto generate it in database, paste it in data grid view in c# if possible

Comment: Please add some code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool CheckExcel(string tableName, string localFileNamePath)
{
    bool status=false;
    string Excel07ConString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + localFileNamePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;IMEX=1'";
    try
    {
        var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", Excel07ConString);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds, "myTable");
        DataTable data = ds.Tables["myTable"];
        //Data table hold only first column of excel file.
        DataTable CustomDT=new DataTable();
        CustomDT.Columns.Add("FirstColumnName", typeof(string));
        foreach(DataRow row in data.Rows)
        {
            CustomDT.Rows.Add(row("Columnn name in excel").ToString());
        }
        DataGridView.DateSource=CustomDt;
        //Function to write data in database.
        string sqlConnection = "Data Source=Database path";
        SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(sqlConnection);
        conn.Open();
        foreach(DataRow row in data.Rows)
        {
            string qryUser = "Insert into TableName(Column) values('" + row["ColumnName"].ToString() + "')";
            var comCheck = new SqlCeCommand(qryUser, conn);
            comCheck.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        comCheck.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```